# How to set the default button for a TextBox in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, defaultbutton

I have a page that has two buttons, btnSearch and btnAddUser. The aspx page is as below. As you can see the default button is btnAddUser. But I would like to set the default button to btnSearch when I type something in the text box txtFilter. I added a JavaScript function clickButton, and in the page_load I added following code. The problem is when I press enter after I type something in the text box, both btnSearch and  btnAddUser are clicked. Is there any way I could do so that btnAddUser is not clicked.

```
 txtFilter.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return clickButton(event, '" + btnSearch.ClientID + "')");

<asp:Panel ID="MainPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnAddUser">
    <table align="center" width="900">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width="70%">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilter" runat="server" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                    onclick="btnSearch_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
            </td>
            <td align="right" width="30%">
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddUser" runat="server" Text="Add User" Width="85px" 
                    CausesValidation="False" onclick="btnAddUser_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
...
</asp:Panel>

function clickButton(e, buttonid) {
            var evt = e ? e : window.event;
            var bt = document.getElementById(buttonid);
            if (bt) {
                if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
                    bt.click();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

UPDATE:
After googling, i found a solution as below. It seems working. But it is not working on Firefox? Anyone know how to resolve it?

```
function clickButton(e, buttonid) {
            var evt = e ? e : window.event;
            var keycode = evt.keyCode || evt.which || evt.charCode;
            var bt = document.getElementById(buttonid);
            if (bt) {
                if (keycode == 13) {
                    evt.cancelBubble = true;
                    evt.returnValue = false;
                    if (evt.stopPropagation) {
                        evt.stopPropagation();
                        evt.preventDefault();
                    }
                    bt.click();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This link might help you out:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35180/How-To-set-Default-Button-for-ENTER-key-pressed-ev

Comment: You may want to look into jQuery's `keypress` event. It tends to be much more reliable. http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: For firefox, your standard CTRL / ALT / SHIFT are found in e.originalEvent.  Such as, e.originalEvent.shiftKey (You can see the others using firebug)

Answer (score 13):

You don't need javascript just wrap search text box in another panel and set default button, something like this (i stripped table tags) :

```
  <asp:Panel ID="MainPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnAddUser">
    <asp:Panel ID="searchPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilter" runat="server" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
        CausesValidation="false" onclick="btnSearch_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddUser" runat="server" Text="Add User" Width="85px" CausesValidation="False" onclick="btnAddUser_Click" />
  </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I tried, but both buttons get clicked when press enter in the textbox.

Comment: you press enter in txtFilter textbox ? I tested in IE, Firefox, Chrome and only search button is clicked. Could you please make small project with just this markup and test it.

Comment: Just tried. Somehow, the btnSearch worked. But when I press enter anywhere else except the textbox, the btnAddUser was not clicked.

Comment: Where is that other control that has the focus when you press enter ?

Comment: I only have one text box, a grid view and couple of buttons in my page.

Comment: are they inside mainpanel ? I tried to put TextBox above btnAddUser and it works OK

Comment: That is probably the problem. I don't have another text box that could gain focus.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9688/discussion-between-antonio-bakula-and-gaolai-peng)

Comment: So does it work, or not? Please comment what's wrong with this approach, or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `TextBox` in a `Panel`, and set the `DefaultButton` property.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilter" runat="server" Width="200" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
        onclick="btnSearch_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score -1):

### JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function kPress(evnt, ID) {
        var ButtonID = ID.id;
        var btnSearchID = ButtonID.replace('txtFilter', 'btnSearch');
        document.getElementById(btnSearchID).click();
    }
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFilter" runat="server" Width="200" onkeypress="kPress(event, this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, i am using master/content page. But I tried your method, not working.

Comment: It will work for Content pages as well. Have you tried with setting debugger in your javascript ?

Comment: Yes. Everytime I try to type something, it will step into the javascript func, not even wait until i press enter.

Comment: I only want the search button gets click when i press enter in the text box. Otherwise the default button is btnAddUser.